# Flutter Divider class cannot be used anymore?

Tags: flutter

Since a couple of days I'm unable to use the Divider class:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html

Both Android Studio and VSCode underline it as error and I cannot compile, the error says:

> The class 'Divider' doesn't have an unnamed constant constructor.  Try
> calling a different constructor.

It is normally used in the code such as in Listview:

```
ListView.separated(
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => const Divider(height: 2.0,),
  itemCount: 5,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
...
```

or within a column:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
     child: Card(
       child: SizedBox.expand(),
       ),
     ),
     Divider(),
....
```

The code hasn't been changed and has normally compiled up to three days ago.

Comment: what file do you see if you Ctrl- click on `Divider`? is it `material/divider.dart`

Comment: On which editor VSC or Android studio ? By the way none of them using Ctrl + Click or Command + click (I'm on Mac) gives back any info. I tried already to include widget instead materail library and swap the order or specify wich one use, no result.

Comment: I mean "go to symbol definition" action, on Linux for both IDEs it's ctrl-click

Comment: On mac is F12, it says 'No definition found for 'Divider', ??!!

Comment: whaaat? Ok, what about other types? For example type `Widget child`, place the cursor on `Widget` and press f12 again

Comment: All other types, classes bring me to their definition ... All projects that use Divider class have the same problem. I'll reinstall flutter ... or I'll try on another system

Comment: I would first start with an empty project, type `flutter create foo` and try your `Divider` there

Comment: Unfortunately, after flutter reinstallation and new project as suggested by psink, Divider is still missing; to momentary survive, I substituted all ListView.separated with ListView.builder and created the divider using Container Decoration using Border conditionally. I'll check on other environment during next week

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255850/discussion-between-thefrankie-and-pskink).